# Homotopy groups of $n$-torus with a point removed.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a simple way how to compute and present homotopy groups of $T^n=S^1\times \ldots\times S^1$ with a point (or several points) removed?

Comment: For $n = 2$ removing one or more points gets you a bouquet of one or more circles and the homotopy groups are straightforward to compute in this case. For higher $n$ I don't know what happens. I think removing the first point is equivalent to removing the top-dimensional cell in a minimal CW decomposition.

Comment: (Replace "one or more circles" with "two or more circles.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For $n=2$ $\mathbb{T}^{2}\setminus\{p\}$ is homotopically equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$ so the fundamental group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ and higher homotopy groups are trivial.
- For $n>2$ Van Kampen theorem assures you that
  $$\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^{n})\cong\pi_{1}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})*_{\pi_1(S^{n-1})} \pi_1(D^n)\cong\pi_{1}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})$$
  thus
  $$\pi_{1}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{T}^{n})\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{Z}\ .$$
  The universal cover is $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ which is homotopically equivalent to an infinite wedge of $S^{n-1}$, so for $k>1$ $$\pi_{k}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})\cong\pi_{k}(\bigvee_{i=1}^\infty S^{n-1})\ .$$
  In particular $\pi_{k}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})\cong0$ for $1<k<n-1$ and $\displaystyle\pi_{n-1}(\mathbb{T}^{n}\setminus\{p\})\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$.

If you take out more than one point, say $r$ points: for $n=2$ you have a fundamental group that is isomorphic to a free product of $r+1$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and again trivial higher homotopy groups. For $n>2$ it should be the same as the case of a single point removed.

Comment: Just a remark: if I understand it right, the computation of higher homotopy groups of the wedge of spheres is complicated, but probably studied in the literature..

Comment: I tried to look for references, but at the moment I cannot download papers... Maybe you can find something here: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2373007?uid=3738296&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104215243107